# How to read the changes in the git diff HEAD file_name?

Tags: git, git-diff

I want if the entered file name in the command `git diff HEAD file_name` have some changes I want to match with a string. For example if the file has changes related to this string `"folder1/folder2"` suppose this is a library which is added in the code file then it will ignore else will detect and return me. Is there is any flag that I use for this or any changes in the command?

Comment: Pipe it to grep

Comment: Is there any method without using grep?@leoOrion

Comment: You can search a git commit message with a git command but not the actual diff itself as the diff has nothing to do with git but the file content itself. I dont think git provides any way